# A relation in inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Question :** Prove that $$\frac{1}{2}\cot^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2\sqrt[3]{4}+1}{\sqrt3}{}\right)+ \frac{1}{3}\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{ \sqrt[3]{4}+1}{\sqrt3}{}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

**Attempt:**

$$\frac{1}{2}\cot^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2\sqrt[3]{4}+1}{\sqrt3}{}\right) = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{ \sqrt[3]{4}+1}{\sqrt3}{}\right)\right)$$
$$3\cot^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2\sqrt[3]{4}+1}{\sqrt3}{}\right) = 2\cot^{-1}\left(\dfrac{ \sqrt[3]{4}+1}{\sqrt3}{}\right)$$

Now if we just take $\cot$ on both sides and we know the formula for $\cot(3\theta)$ and $\cot(2\theta)$, it can be brute forced but is there any other easier method to this...